# Html5 forms and offline storage in IPAD App

Tags: ipad, html, uiwebview, offline

I am working on a IPAD application with a forms component that must support offline functionality. The forms in question are written in HTML5 and rendered within the app using a UIWebView IOS control. Are there any libraries/frameworks that allow for me to save the HTML5 form data to the device periodically? The data must be encrypted on the device as security of the data is a huge concern.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 itself supports offline storage. You can try that out.